# ssh.net sshclient run command grep

Tags: c#, linux, ssh.net

I am quite knew to ssh client and linux commands. But I set up the SshClient to log into a linux machine and was able to connect (or I think). I need to run a grep on a file path but when I run the code below the result value return nothing back. What am I doing wrong in the runcommand?

```
string strOut = string.Empty;
string ppkFile = @"F:\user\convertedppk";
var pkf = new[] { new PrivateKeyFile(ppkFile) };

// Install-Package SSH.NET – nugget package
using (var client = new SshClient("host", "username", pkf))
{
   client.Connect();
   var result = client.RunCommand("grep –ri 'exception'  /temp/local/log/20200402");
   strOut = result.Result;
   client.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Did you try reading `result.Error` and `result.ExitStatus`?

Comment: no wasnt aware of it thanks

Answer (score 0):

grep -ri 'file/path/here/ -e 'exception'

Comment: Do it mean that your shell command was wrong? So it was not a programming issue at all?